# How to store an array remotely to a db from my iOS app

Tags: ios, nsarray

I need to store an array remotely from my app then retrieve it whenever i need it.
Also i need to sort this array for getting datas in a chronological order.
I have never done this before can anyone tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB is remote ? If YES you should create API interface to the remote DB and then use this API in your iOS app to interact with DB.
Good article to explain how to create simple API and use it in the iOS application is here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course